# How Split string of sector for populate list of sector

Tags: c#

I'm a novice programmer and maybe the problem is trivial.
I have a string containing the various sectors and I would like to split it to populate a list based on the values ​​contained in the starting string.
for example:
The starting string contain:

1. LS1_9 Molecular mechanisms of signalling processes
2. LS1_7 Molecular biophysics, biomechanics, bioenergetics

Starting from this I want to populate a list that contains the value of 1 in the first place and the value of 2 in the second place and so on.

how can I split the starting string to get the desired effect?

thank you all.

Comment: So you have one big, multiline string? And each line in the string starts with a number followed by a period `.`? And you want a `List<int>` containing all the (parsed) numbers from the starts of the lines in the string?

Answer (score -1):

You can use String.Split() to separate each value into an array first.

Then make a new array of length: Array 1's length + Array 2's length

And finally use a for loop, you could use the % operator to alternate between getting array values.

Hope this helps!